# Sending a contact from an iOS app via bluetooth

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, gamekit, vcf-vcard

I am trying to allow a user, who is running my app, to send a contacts vcard (vcf) via bluetooth to another iOS device.
The problem is, that the receiving device should not be required to run the same app.

Is there a possibiliy to accomplish this?

If there is not - is it at least possible to have Gamekit to establish a session, when the receiving device is running the same app, but without requiring the (receiving) user to start the peerPicker-dialog?

Any help and hints are appreciated!

Comment: it seems to me that there really is not such a possibility. What I did now is to have a GKSession running in the background of the app, which the other device can connect to using the GKPeerPickerController. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option: seems to be impossible.

Second option: Works. I implemented a GKSessionDelegate for receiving incoming connections. This session is startet together with the app.
For establishing the connection with a receiver, I used the well known GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate.

One remainig problem is, that the sender sees itself in the list of available peers (because it has also a receiver running in the background). My solution for this is to set its GKSession.available=NO, as soon as the sender starts its GKPeerPickerController.